# How to cast an array from Firestore in dart

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class

```
UserModel{
late final List<UserEmail> emails;
}
```

I trying to retrieve an array from Firestore.

```
UserModel.fromJson(    emails = json[emailsKey] != null
            ? (json[emailsKey] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>).map((Map<String, dynamic> email) => UserEmail.fromJson(email)).toList()
            : <UserEmail>[],
```

The `emailsKey` is the key to emails array in Firestore..

The error I'm getting back is

```
Failed: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast<…>
```

I'm not sure why my casting isn't working (at runtime).
Any ideas

Comment: Does @George Keogh [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69862099) works for you? If not, could you provide a bit more context? Such as a sample of the JSON response you're receiving and parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var temp = json[emailsKey];
List<String> emailKeys = List<String>.from(temp);
```